# How To: Simple R Graphic of 2 sets of points overlayed on same plot

Tags: r, plot

I would like to overlay two sets of points on one graph.

```
x1 = rnorm(20, mean = 2, sd = 0.25)
x2 = rnorm(20, mean = 10, sd = 0.1)
y = rep(1,20)

plot(x = x1, y,
     main = "Enzyme Activities",
     pch = 16,
     col = "red")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x = x2, y,
     pch = 5,
     col = "blue")
```

My current graph is overlapping oddly...
[image]

Comment: What do you not like about your current display?

Comment: just added .png;  perplexed by the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acutally I found `stripchart` which is better.

```
x1 = rnorm(20, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.5)

x2 = rnorm(20, mean = 4, sd = 0.5)

stripchart(x = x1,
           main = "Test #1",
           xlab = "Km",
           xlim = c(0, 6),
           pch = 16,
           col = "green")
points(x = x2, y, col = "blue")
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
plot(x = x1, y,
     main = "Enzyme Activities",
     xlim = c(0, 15),
     pch = 16,
     col = "blue")
points(x = x2, y,
       col=2)
```

Cheers